# Laravel: CKEditor: how to use image plugin while using cdn ckeditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, laravel-5.6, ckeditor4.x

I'm currently trying to integrate ckeditor in my `laravel blog` and I wan't to add the `image plugin` because I need to be able to upload images. I'm using `cdn of ckeditor`. I have seen similar questions being asked here in the past, I have tried all of their solutions but they don't work for me.

Problem: When I click the image button in the toolbar the standard image window pops up instead of the image plugin.

I have added the image plugin code locally to my project:

```
     Path to plugin: public/ckeditor/image
```

As you can see in the code as suggested on stackoverflow I added the `addExternal function` with a tailing `/` in the plugin path and used `extraPlugin attribute` in the ckeditor configuration.

Thanks in advance.

```
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
                    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.1/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>



            <div class="row pb-lg-5">
                <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                        <textarea cols="80" id="ckEditor" name="ckEditor" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('image', '/public/ckEditor/image/', 'plugin.js');

                CKEDITOR.replace('ckEditor', {
                    height: 400,
                    extraPlugins: 'image'
                });
            </script>
```